# Limiting distance of RFID readers

Tags: distance, rfid, reader

We are currently working on a warehouse management project that includes RFID tags and readers.

we're still at the beginning of it and are trying to design the different solutions.

Here's my situation : 
We're going to have RFID tags (most likely UHF) on each of our devices we track.

Picture our current warehouse as a small room with shelves rows, and each shelve will have its own RFID reader, aimed to track the location of the devices.

We want our warehouse workers to scan their device on the reader before they store a device in.

My question is :

What are the possibilities around RFID technologies, which would allow us to ensure our RFID readers won't conflict each other and start discovering tags they shouldn't , especially because we have UFH tags?

Can we get the distance of a device we just scanned and ignore what's over 10/15 cm ? Can we limit the discovery range of the reader?

Thanks for reading me though.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much every UHF reader can be set to a reduced output power. This results in a reduced read range. However, the results are not easy to predict, they require testing. And the read range may change if the environment changes (position of shelves, metal objects in the vicinity...).